# Remove an argument from a Ruby method call at the root of a class. On-the-fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Here is a Ruby class:

```
class User
  devise :trackable, :confirmable
end
```

For most instances I want `:confirmable` to be present, but for some instances, I would like to remove `:confirmable` before instantiation.

**QUESTION:** How to remove `:confirmable` on-the-fly?

I would rather avoid creating a separate class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`devise :confirmable` adds a number of methods to your model, one of which is  [`skip_confirmation!`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#skip_confirmation!-instance_method):

> If you don’t want confirmation to be sent on create, neither a code to
>   be generated, call skip_confirmation!

Example:

```
  user = User.new
  user.skip_confirmation!
```

Comment: this works too, instead of user.confirm! , but still needs to be tied-in with a customized "confirmation_required?()" logic..

Comment: Note for readers: skip_confirmation! works after User.new but not after User.create (which I guess is kind of User.new followed by user.save!)

Answer (score 1):

You will need the migrations for both :trackable and :confirmable in any case for your DB.

Wouldn't it be easier to just have :confirmable defined for both cases, but in the case you don't want it, you can automatically confirm the user account from within the controller, after the user is created?

see:
   https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

lines 27..30 contain the before_create and after_create hooks

you'll need to do this modification:

you'll need to override :confirmation_required? ,  so that it returns true 
   only in the cases where you want a confirmation token to be generated and a confirmation email to be sent.
   In the case you don't need the confirmation email, you can do a user.confirm! after creating the user account.
   You could put this in as an additional after_create action.

e.g.

```
module Devise
  module Models
     module Confirmable
       after_create  :confirm! , :if => :confirmation_not_required?    # you'll need to define that method

       private 
       def confirmation_required?   # overriding the default behavior
         your_special_conditions && !confirmed?
       end

       def confirmation_not_required?
         ! confirmation_required?
       end
     end
  end
end
```

Note:
Instead of user.confirm!  you could also use user.skip_confirmation!